# String Parameter Typeof ERROR JavaScript

Tags: javascript

first time here so hopefully I got everything right.
I'm still rather new to JavaScript so apologies if this is a simple mess up on my end. I need to get the length the parameter type of says is a string... I'm lost I would appreciate any help thanks.

```html
<button style="position: absolute; top: 0px;" onclick="typeWriter('hello world', '70')">CLICK ME</button>

<p style="padding-top: 50px; text-align: center;" id="loadingText" class="loadingTitle"></p>

<script>
  var letters;
  var i = 0;

  function typeWriter(text, speed) {
    console.log(text)
    var textLength = text.length;
    if (i < textLength) {
      document.getElementById("loadingText").innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
      i++;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
      if (i == Math.max(textLength)) {

      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You have not defined the variable `text`.

Comment: You need to open the dev tools and see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple issues here:

1. You mean `input` not `text`
2. You need to keep passing your two arguments on recursion in setTimeout
3. If you want to run something else on the last loop, just use an `else {}` statement ([`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) is for finding the max among 2+ numbers)

```js
var i = 0;

function typeWriter(input, speed) {
  if (i < input.length) {
    document.getElementById("loadingText").innerHTML += input[i];
    i++;
    setTimeout(function () { typeWriter(input, speed) }, speed);
   } else {
     // final stuff
   }
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  typeWriter('hello world', 70);
});
```

```html
<button id="button" style="position: absolute; top: 0px;">CLICK ME</button>

<p style="padding-top: 50px; text-align: center;" id="loadingText" class="loadingTitle"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change 'input' var for 'text' var in function params.

```html
<button style="position: absolute; top: 0px;" onclick="typeWriter('hello world', '70')">CLICK ME</button>

<p style="padding-top: 50px; text-align: center;" id="loadingText" class="loadingTitle"></p>

<script>
            var letters;
            var i = 0;

function typeWriter(text, speed) {
            console.log(text)
            var textLength = text.length;
            if (i < textLength) {
            document.getElementById("loadingText").innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
            i++;
            setTimeout(typeWriter, +speed);
            if (i == Math.max(textLength)) {
                
            }
        }
    }  
</script>
```

Comment: hey mate, sorry that was me trying to fix it with another line of code that I removed before posting. the same problem persists.